# Fetch ids of live posts only (not posts with other statuses) and change status with a button in candidate dashboard

Tags: functions, post-status, get-post

I have added a button in posts list in candidate dashboard that changes status of all posts to "offline" first, then updates the current post to "publish". **I want to do this: fetch ids of all live posts only and change their status to "offline" instead of other posts with different statuses like "approved", "pending" etc.**
***In other words only one resume can be set live.***

Here is the code I am using

```
* Publish a CV from front-end candidate dashboard
*/
function myresumeFunction($current_post_id){

  $post_id= get_the_ID();

   //Update all post into draft status
   $live_resumes = get_post( $post_id, 'ARRAY_A' );
  
  $live_resumes ['post_status'] = 'offline';
 
 // Update the post into the database
  wp_update_post($live_resumes);


// Update Current post into live status
    $current_post = get_post( $current_post_id, 'ARRAY_A' );
    $current_post ['post_status'] = 'publish'; 
   
 // Update the post into the database
    wp_update_post($current_post);

}

// Update Current post into live status
    $current_post = get_post( $current_post_id, 'ARRAY_A' );
    $current_post ['post_status'] = 'publish'; 
   
 // Update the post into the database
    wp_update_post($current_post);

}



function cvLive(){

echo ('<form  method="POST" id="resume_live" ><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.get_the_ID().'" /> <input type="submit"  name="set-cv-live"  id="btn-live" value="Set Live"></form>');

    
    
    
// Show a particular value.
$id = $_POST['id'];


if($id) {
myresumeFunction($id);
}
 
}

add_shortcode('make-cv-live','cvLive');
```

See this image of dashboard
[image]

Comment: I have found a solution my self. Replaced this whole section `//Update all post into draft status
   $live_resumes = get_post( $post_id, 'ARRAY_A' );
  
  $live_resumes ['post_status'] = 'offline';
 
 // Update the post into the database
  wp_update_post($live_resumes);`

Comment: With this `$post_id= get_the_ID();
 $post = get_post($post_id);
 
 //change a "Live" post to "Offline"
 if ( $post->post_status=='publish') {
        $my_post = array(
            'ID' => $post_id,
            'post_status' => 'offline'
        );
 
 wp_update_post($my_post);
     }`